# What are functions of type () => void usually called?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

In the following type definition

```
type Effect = () => void
```

the name `Effect` is not a good choice IMHO.
What could be better name choices for `Effect`? TYVM

BTW: `Callback` is surely one option, but still there may be better names...

Comment: You could call it Mutation.

Comment: C# calls functions that do not return a value `Action` I like that name ..

Comment: Callback or sideEffect, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You are defining a type here, so the most descriptive name for the type should be used.

Using a descriptive name helps others who read the code to understand why the type has been declared, and how to use it, so something like  `FunctionReturningVoid`, or `ReturnsVoid`.